# How can I present a screen that asks users to confirm their account details upon registration?

Tags: users

I have a site for which I would like to display a "confirm details" screen when users create an account.  Basically, I would like something similar to the "required preview" option for adding a node-- just for user registration instead.

I was unable to find a module to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. you have a function for that "**function confirm_form**"

   see this link https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/confirm_form/7

**2. add through js**

```
<?php
    drupal_add_js('(function($){ $(function(){$("#edit-xxxxxx").click(function(){return confirm("confirm do that ?")});}); })(jQuery);', array('type' => 'inline'));
?>
```

refer the above link you will get three different ideas